# ASP.NET Web Application REST JSON always null, even when accepting safely

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, rest, postman

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/restful-web-services.html) on creating a RESTful web service application. I successfully created GET, POST, and DELETE through its instructions using only simple strings. However, I'm now attempting to create a PUT method on my own with a "complex" class (just 2 strings) and no matter how many pages I read about null coming in, nothing seems to make it right. I'm fairly sure the problem is on my JSON sending side (using Postman) not on my RESTful server, but here's the important bits from both:

Complex Class (C#)

```
public class PutData
{
    public string ind { get; set; }
    public string str { get; set; }
}
```

PUT Method (C#)

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/Tutorial",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
public void EditTutorial(Object json) //<- have also tried PutData and string
{
    var jsonString = json.ToString();// this Object implementation is from another S.O. page
    PutData data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PutData>(jsonString);
    int pid;
    Int32.TryParse(data.ind, out pid);
    lst[pid] = data.str;
}
```

JSON sent as PUT (Postman)

```
{ "ind" : "0", "str" : "Dictionary" }
```

My Postman settings are

Body: raw JSON (application/json)

Content-Type: application/json

Any ideas?

Comment: So json parameter is null, so it throws error on 1st line?

Comment: Hits the breakpoint on the first first line, Object json is null, try a step and it's out of the function having thrown nullreferenceexception

Comment: May have stumbled onto the problem or a clue. So even though I'm setting the Content-Type to application/json through the Key/Value of the header in Postman, I'm getting passed back when it fails Content-Type text/html. Or is that normal?

Comment: @NickCondatore You need to set the accept header on the client to get json returned.

Comment: @Eris Can you even set that? it looks to me like it is returned in whatever format the reply is in, which in code I have set to WebMessageFormat.Json, but because it throws an exception it looks like it's getting a default reply with default formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working with some of the oddest syntax I never thought of. The ASP.NET API is doing so much crazy work for us, and it's not necessarily convenient...

```
public void EditTutorial(String ind, String str)
```

This works, crazy enough, so each key can be a param. If we had a giant Json object this would be very inefficient as the function signature would be as massive as the relevant keys, but the work application I'll be applying this to should only need 4-6 keys coming in so this will suffice. I hope there's a way to access the Json coming in directly, or at least access the copy the API is creating without having to use params.

Comment: I've only done this with Web API, and the model binder there will indeed deserialize json into an object like your 'PutData' automatically. In other words what I would write would typically look your original method.